# Printing Two Dimension Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, string

I know this isn't a difficult issue but I have come to a complete stand still, I want to print a two dimension array with values already assigned for example:

```
   int array1[][] = new int[1][1];
          array1[0][0] = 10;
          array1[0][1] = 20;
          array1[1][0] = 30;
          array1[1][1] = 40;
```

I just want to simply print the values and I really can't remember how to do it, I keep on doing this

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array1))`;
```

but I know this is wrong, can you help?

Comment: Not technically 'wrong', but looping through the values with nested for loops can help if you want the actual values.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array ( especially `System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(deepArray));` )

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at the [`Arrays.deepToString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString-java.lang.Object:A-) method, which is similar to `Arrays.toString` except that if the nested objects are arrays, it will recursively (and correctly) convert them into strings as well.

Also, note that there's a slight typo in your code - you need to size the array as

```
int[][] array1 = new int[2][2];
```

since you want a 2x2 array, not a 1x1 array.